# Get the content of Notes Document with attachment file to Solr Document

Tags: java, solr, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Things which i am trying to do is as follows.

I have Notes Document with the fields [from (type:text),To(type:text),                          Attachment(Type:RichText )] and then i trying to create a `SolrDocument` of the Notes Document which i mentioned above.

This after creating the `SolrDocument` and saved it to the Solr Server How my `SolrDocument` looking like as follow.

```
  <doc>

  <str name="contid">340DD508D43F2F2965257ECF0045AF1C</str> // saving the UNID of the doc
   <arr name="cmrights">
       <str>DummyValue</str>
       <str>DummyValue1</str>
       <str>DummyValue2</str>
       <str>DummyValue3</str>
    </arr>
  <str name="frommail">sender@gmail.com</str>

  <date name="posteddate">2015-09-29T12:41:08Z</date> 

  <arr name="sendto">
      <str>receiver@gmial.com</str>
  </arr>

  <str name="subject">NotesSlrWriter</str>

 </doc>
```

To Write above `SolrInputDocument` I use following methods(Its part of my class)

```
private void writeFields() throws Exception {
    writeField("contid", doc.getUniversalID());
    writeField("cmrights", MultiValues);
    writeField("dbtype", arvConfig);

    Collection<IDXField> fields = fieldsToIndex(arvConfig);

    for (IDXField idxField : fields) {

        int type = idxField.getDataType();
        switch (type) {

        case SQLFieldDesc.DATE:

            String DateField = idxField.getArcName();
            Collection<Date> dValues = new ArrayList<Date>();

            String d2 = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray(DateField).get(0)
                    .toString();
            // System.out.println(d2);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

            Date d4 = sdf.parse(d2);

            System.out.println("New Date is: " + d4.toString());
            dValues.add(d4);
            System.out.println(DateField.toLowerCase());
            System.out.println(doc.getItemValue(DateField).toString());
            writeDateField(DateField.toLowerCase(), dValues);
            break;

        case SQLFieldDesc.NUMINT:

            System.out.println("number fields");

            break;

        default:

            final String FieldName = idxField.getArcName();
            writeField(FieldName.toLowerCase(),
                    doc.getItemValueString(idxField.getArcName()));
            System.out.println(FieldName);
            System.out
                    .println(doc.getItemValueString(idxField.getArcName()));
            break;

                            }

                   }



        }
```

So, I want to do something like this.

```
   solrInputDocument.writeFiles(Attachment , files which are attached);
```

Something like i have to write method, But i really don't understand how i could i deal with or how to start with it, the field of Notes Document which is "Attachment" in the RichTextFormat.

i think i can do so this with dxl of my current Document.then i have to get the content via dxl but the problem is how i get that content in the SolrDocument.

There is any way or steps which help me to lead me towards my solution.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What's in the rich text field? Just a file attachnment? Or is there an unpredictable mix of forwarded text, images, attachments, etc.

Comment: yes, its second option its Attachment which can be anything,

Answer (score 1):

You can get the HTML representation of a RichText field with the URL

```
http://server/db.nsf/view/docunid/RichTextFieldname?OpenField
```

Just read RichText field's content in HTML format via http from URL.
Example:

```
http://server/db.nsf/0/AF665BE72463477AC1257EB90039E589/Body?OpenField
```

Comment: Thank you for replying @Knut Herrmann, sorry for previous question i    think it was not that explanatory. I edited my question again.